# fastest way to write spark dataframe to phoenix table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-phoenix

I have a wide phoenix table with > 159 cols and around 60mil recs which I am accessing through spark and reading into spark dataframe and then performing many analytical functions. In the end however when i try to write this processed dataframe with only 7 mils recs to another table in Phoenix using "df.write" but its very slow. It takes 58 mins to write this data. My question is, is there a better way to write data from spark dataframe to phoenix table?
Please suggest.

Comment: can you run pure SQL? you could to a UPSERT SELECT.  I was able to upload 2 million records to a temporary table and UPSERT SELECT to another table in about 8 minutes (3 data nodes).  Maybe that's the trick to use UPSERT SELECT

Comment: Thanks Paul; I am however doing many analytical operations that are best done in Spark dataframe like "windowing"; and then load this df to a table n phoenix; I agree on the upsert part; its pretty fast. But do we have a fast way to save df in phonix